# VBA Print Macro without cell formatting

Tags: excel, vba

this is my current code to print these cells

```
Sub printSticker()
    Worksheets("Sticker").Range("A1:D4:B6").PrintOut
End Sub
```

But this way it keeps the formatting on them, so I can choose where they are going (they have to fit on a pre-printed sticker)

For example

On D4 it will include the cells from A4 B4 and C4 so there is a wide space before D4

I would like to remove this space so A1 D4 and B6 are in a neat line stacked on top of each other

[image: this is what it looks like]

spreadsheet

[image: spreadsheet]

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you are asking. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sorry, i've tried to explain more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preview what you are printing by either adding `Preview:=True` at the end of your expression

```
Worksheets("Sticker").Range("A1:D4:B6").PrintOut Preview:=True
```

or `File` » `Print`

Ok, you need to align your values using the alignment controls on the toolbar

[image: alignment]

Also you can hit <kbd>F1</kbd> and type **`Print Labels`** to get step-by-step guide.

Comment: This is what it looks like http://i.imgur.com/ZjNROzr.png

Comment: There is no way to do that within print preview and the cells are already justified to the left within the workbook, is there anyway to do it with VB?

Comment: can you show a screenshot of the spreadsheet?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/NKCzfCs.png 
Basically I have 100s of worksheets and I was making a macro to save time editing each one, would storing each cell as a variable then printing that variable work better?